# Can I install a 150A breaker if the the outdoor MCCB is 100 A?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I have a villa, which is 375m<sup>2</sup>. On the boundary wall of the villa I have a molded case circuit breaker (MCCB) rated for 100A. I need to install a main distribution panel (MDP) inside the villa. The demand load is 75.5A.

Can I install a 150A circuit breaker as the main breaker in the MDP?

Comment: Yes, you can put a 150A breaker behind a 100A breaker. It just means your 100A MCCB will trip before the 150A in the MDP. Though that depends on the trip curve of the breakers. But why not simply buy a load center with a main lugs instead of a main breaker? Should be cheaper and eliminates the redundant second breaker. And you are very close to the limits of your service if you are drawing 75A. How did you predict the load? You have little room to grow. And not to be one of those scolding types but you might want to call a licensed, bonded and insured electrician.

Comment: that would make an expensive switch.  is that what you need?